# How do signals propagate down unballanced coaxial transmission lines?

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, electric-circuits, maxwell-equations, waveguide

I have previously asked a related question however it was closed, thus I have sorted out my thoughts into this revised question. This new question comes in two parts.

I do not understand the concept of an unbalanced transmission line. Online explanations have confused me and perhaps others who have found this post in the future.

1
Balanced transmission lines are defined as two parralel conductors each with equal characteristic impedances which acts as a waveguide for electromagnetic radiation. However I have read that a balanced transmission line can carry an unbalanced signal. How does this fit in with the idea of a propagating electromagnetic wave if it is possible at all?

2
I do not conceptually or mathematicaly understand how two parralel conductors in an unbalanced line such as coaxial cable are able to propagate an electromagnetic wave, resulting from the definition of such a line being that both lines have different impedences and thus different voltage current ratios and different propagation speeds. Hence I'm interested to know what is actually happening within a coaxial transmission line pertaining to voltage and current distribution, wave propagation, and the grounding of the coaxial outer conductor.

Comments to good sources on this topic would be greatly appreciated along with any answers.

Comment: As @HEMMI implies below a "wire" has no impedance as such. Impedance is a concept that is attached to a specific spatial distribution of conductors and insulators *and* a voltage (or current) source. A transmission line (a pair of conductors) in the abstract is not "balanced"; instead for a given geometrically symmetrical transmission line if it is driven by source in a anti-symmetrical (+/-) manner in an *electrical* voltage sense taken relative to the geometrically symmetric plane we call that "balanced".

Comment: Any introductory electromagnetics textbook should spend 2 or 3 chapters answering your 2nd question.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps my idea is not a good answer,
but due to the limited size of the comment field,
I will put my thoughts here.

What you wrote "coaxial cable ... being that both lines have different impedences" is unconvincing.
Since coaxial cables transmit the TEM waves, they have only one characteristic impedance value.
The characteristic impedance is not specific to the metal wire,
but is specific to the insulating material together with the boundary conditions
(the metal wire sets the boundary conditions).
Electromagnetic wave energy is dominantly transmitted through insulators even in low frequencies,
and the energy of electromagnetic waves transmitted through metallic objects is very small.
I think the idea of impedance of metal wires is not a good idea.

I think solving the following exercise in the textbook may be helpful.
Problem 8.3; A transmission line consisting of two concentric circular cylinders ...
Page 397 Chapter 8 (J.D. Jackson, Classical Electrodynamics, 3rd ed.)

Comment: ... is what I would think, yet everywhere online says they have different impedances. I'll check out the exercises you referenced soon, thanks.

Comment: It seems the source is a little above my level. Maybe I should just wait for all this until I get to learning Maxwell's equations in depth?

Comment: If your specialty is not physics, it is understandable that you do not want to learn Maxwell's equations from a  book. However, I recommend that you study in a book.
At the same time, following the adage "practice makes perfect", I recommend that you use computer simulations in conjunction to look at various types of electromagnetic wave propagation. Actually, I have never used it, and it is somewhat irresponsible, but, for exaple, the software [meep]([https://meep.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is free and seems to be able to calculate transmission lines.

Comment: No not at all, I am not opposed to learning Maxwell's equations from a book before I start uni. However I am still building up my mathematical basis bit by bit, therefore it will take at least a few months before I can check out the book you recommended and thus learn the concepts in deapth. I will certainly check out that simulation however so I can maybe gain an intuitive understanding.